# Multiple Database connections using UPDATE ... RETURNING, seem to not update rows in tasks table

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, isolation-level, autocommit

## Preface

I want to process tasks listed in a database table in parallel. Not looking for working code.

## The Setup

- 1 PostgreSQL database server **D**
- 1 processing server **P**
- 1 User terminal **T**

using Python 3.6, psycopg2.7.6, PostgreSQL 11

**D** holds tables with data to be processed and a `tasks` table. A user at **T** `ssh`'s into **P**, where the following command can be issued:

```
python -m core.utils.task
```

This `task.py` script is essentially a `while` loop that gets a task `t` from the `tasks` table on **D** with the status 'new' until there are no new tasks left. A task `t` is basically a set of arguments for another function called `do_something(t)`. `do_something(t)` itself will make many connections to **D** to get data that needs to be processed and set task's to status 'done' once it finished – the `while` loop starts all over and gets a new task.

In order to run `python -m core.utils.task` multiple times I open multiple `ssh` connections. Not so good, I know; `threading` or `multiprocessing` would be better. But his is just for testing if I can run the mentioned command twice.

There is a script that manages all the database interactions called `pgsql.py` which is needed to get a task and then by `do_something(t)`. I adapted a singleton pattern from [this SE post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/358061/348371).

## Pseudo-Code (mostly)

**task.py**

```py
import mymodule
import pgsql

def main():
    while True:
        r, c = pgsql.SQL.select_task()  # rows and columns
        task = dotdict(dict(zip(c, r[0])))
        mymodule.do_something(task)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**mymodule.py**

```py
import pgsql

def do_something(t):
    input = pgsql.SQL.get_images(t.table,t.schema,t.image_id,t.image_directory)
    some_other_function(input)
    pgsql.SQL.task_status(t.task_id,'done')
```

**pgsql.py**

```py
import psycopg2 as pg

class Postgres(object):
    """Adapted from https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/358061/348371"""
    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = object.__new__(cls)
            db_config = {'dbname': 'dev01', 'host': 'XXXXXXXX',
                         'password': 'YYYYY', 'port': 5432, 'user': 'admin'}
            try:
                print('connecting to PostgreSQL database...')
                connection = Postgres._instance.connection = pg.connect(**db_config)
                connection.set_session(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED', autocommit=True)
            except Exception as error:
                print('Error: connection not established {}'.format(error))
                Postgres._instance = None

            else:
                print('connection established')

        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = self._instance.connection

    def query(self, query):
        try:
            with self.connection.cursor() as cur:
                cur.execute(query)
                rows = cur.fetchall()
                cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
        except Exception as error:
            print('error execting query "{}", error: {}'.format(query, error))
            return None
        else:
            return rows, cols

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()

db = Postgres()
class SQL():
    def select_task():
        s = """
            UPDATE schema.tasks
               SET status = 'ready'
             WHERE task_id = (  SELECT task_id
                                  FROM schema.tasks
                                 WHERE tasks.status = 'new'
                                 LIMIT 1)
            RETURNING *
            ;
            """.format(m=mode)
        return Postgres.query(db, s)


    def task_status(id,status):
        s = """
            UPDATE
                schema.tasks
            SET
                status = '{s}'
            WHERE
                tasks.task_id = '{id}'
            ;
            """.format(s=status,
                       id=id)
        return Postgres.query(db, s)
```

## Problem

This works with one `ssh` connection. Tasks are retrieved from the database and processed, once finished the task is set to 'done'. Once I open a second `ssh` connection in a second terminal to run `python -m core.utils.task` (so to say, in parallel) the exact same rows of the tasks table are processed in both - ignoring that they have been updated.

## Question

What are your suggestions to get this to work? There are millions of tasks and I need to run them in parallel. Before implementing `threading` or `multiprocessing` I wanted to test it with multiple `ssh` connections first, bad idea? I have fiddled around with the `isolation levels` and `autocommit` settings in `psycopg2`'s `set_session()` but without luck. I checked the sessions in the Database server and can see that each process of `python -m core.utils.task` has its own PID, only connecting once, exactly like this singleton pattern should work. Any ideas or pointers how to deal with this are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that performing one task is not an atomic operation. Therefore, in different ssh sessions, the same task can be processing several times.

> In this implementation, you can try to use an `"INPROGRESS"` status for task so as not to retrieve tasks that are already being processed (with `"INPROGRESS"` status). **But be sure to use autocommit.**

But I would implement this using threads and database connection pool. And would extract tasks in batches using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. The `do_something`, `select_task` and `task_status` functions would implement for batch of tasks.

Also, there is no need to implement the `Postgres` class as a singleton.

---

**Amended (see the comments below)**

- You can add `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` to the SQL query in current implementation (see [url](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1)).
- If you want to work with batches, then separate the data by some serial column (well, or just sort the data in a table).
- [My implementation using batches](https://pastebin.com/qTDAJ3hA).
- This can be implemented using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `PersistentConnectionPool`.

Comment: Thanks @Rustam, I use a `status =  'ready' ` in the `UPDATE... RETURNING` statement. To work in batches is a good idea. Can you please explain a bit more about the threads an connection pool, it sounds like a solution.

Comment: [Implementation example using OFFSET/LIMIT and threads](https://pastebin.com/qTDAJ3hA). Also, `do_something` function can be parallelized in the same way.

I will assume that in your case the problem is in the nested select in `select_task` function. Maybe you can add `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` after `LIMIT 1` in this function ([see](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69471/postgres-update-limit-1)).

Comment: @Michael, I got a 35 percent reduction in program execution time (from 23m to 15m) on 2 threads compared to 1.

For the test, I used 10000000 rows in the tasks table and machine with 4 virtual cores (Intel Core i5-4210U 1.7 GHz) and 4 GB RAM.

Comment: your answer and implementation example are helpful. I implemented the `ThreadedConnectionPool` and used `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` but did not go with batches. If `thread_pool` is needed by a function in another module to execute a query, is it advisable to make it a global variable (same for the semaphore)?

Comment: If you run your program in one thread, then use `SimpleConnectionPool`. 

Otherwise, if you want to use the thread pool (eg. see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)), then use `PersistentConnectionPool` or `ThreadedConnectionPool`.

Comment: In my implementation, I processed every batch in new thread, so I used a semaphore to limit the number of batches processed simultaneously. Because in Ubuntu there is a limit on the number of running threads. And it also makes sense to limit the number of running threads depending on the number of cores in the processor (Usually `2 x number of virtual cores`). And because of the chosen implementation, I used `ThreadedConnectionPool`.

Comment: **If you plan to use a thread pool, then it makes no sense to use semaphore.**

**Thread pool can be placed in the main function.**

If you want to work with batches, then separate the data by some serial column (well, or just sort the data in a table).

Comment: **Correction.** For computations, the optimal number of threads is `2 x number of virtual cores (on the computer where the program runs)` (but there is GIL in python, so it makes no sense). For connections to the DB, the optimal number of threads is `2 x number of physical cores + effective_spindle_count (on the computer where the database is located)` (see [url](https://urrl.ru/Q5t5h5)). For receiving data via TCP sockets, you can run quite a few threads depending on the size of batch, the size of RAM and other restrictions on your computer. **This is the place to experiment.**

Comment: **Use batches.** Even if you would communicate with the database via unix sockets (*preferably if the DB is on the same computer as the program. If not, then this option is not available*), but now you use TCP sockets, which are slower, the slowest place in your program is requests to the DB. Therefore use batches of data. *You need to find the optimal ratio between the size of the batch and the number of requests to DB.*